# load balancing elasticsearch nodes for document / index writes and updates?

Tags: elasticsearch, load-balancing

I am architecting a medium sized elasticsearch cluster (~20 nodes) with [the three distinct node types Elasticsearch allows (master, data, and client)](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html)

I am working on setting up load balancers to receive new documents and document updates for the Elasticsearch cluster.

I have found Elasticsearch documentation on [routing a document to a shard](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html).  But have not found if this routing takes place on a specific node type (i.e. only master nodes perform document routing; or if master and data nodes perform document routing)?

Another way of asking this is: will any node type in the Elasticsearch cluster perform a shard routing lookup when a document write is received and route the write/update request to the correct shard -- or does only the master node perform shard routing lookups for document writes/updates?

Knowing which node types perform document to shard routing is important to the load balancer setup.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question i need to start from cluster state.
Cluster state has all information about the cluster mainly what all index exists , how many shard each index has and on which nodes these shards are maintained.

This cluster state , though maintained by master node , all the nodes has a copy of it. Which means the master is never a single point of failure , any node can route an index call to the right shard.
Now only the master node can make any change to the cluster state. This means that if a new index is made , or if a new machines comes or goes from  cluster , the master node make the change to the cluster state and broadcasts them to all the nodes.

Even if the master goes down , some other node would be elected as master.

Now coming back to your question routing can happen on any node and there is no point in load balancer , at-least while indexing. The index request no matter to which node it hits , would be routed to a single machine to which document should go. By creating several shards , you are already applying a load balancing logic there.

Comment: Thank you for the explination about cluster state.  [The Elasticsearch documentation on cluster state,](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-state.html) was exactly the information I needed.

The master node keeps the cluster state "shard routing table" and distributes the routing table to all other nodes in the cluster